# What is the legal basis of speed signs in Victoria, Australia?

Tags: speeding

When I went for my driver's licence test, they told me to follow the speed signs on the side of the road.

What law requires me to obey these signs, and what law authorises whoever puts the signs there to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Road Rules in Australia in each state and territory are based on the [Model Road Rules 2012](http://www.ntc.gov.au/Media/Reports/(F1D63B25-98A0-8E5A-EBD4-BA6FC69ABF7D).pdf).

Each state and territory has enacted these rules (with some modifications; mainly relating to administrative matters) through their respective parliaments. The laws specifically for Victoria are the [Road Safety Road Rules 2009](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/consol_reg/rsrr2009208/) (Part 3 of which includes the obligation to obey speed limit signs) and the [Road Safety (Traffic Management) Regulations 2009](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/consol_reg/rsmr2009373/) (Part 2 of which says who can put up what speed signs where and prohibit ordinary people from doing so), both made under the [Road Safety Act 1996](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/consol_act/rsa1986125/) (section 95 and Schedule 2, items 44 and 45).

Comment: Thanks for this. The most relevant rules seem to be rule 20 (obey the speed limit) and rule 21 (the speed limit may be specified on a sign). However, where does it say who can erect a speed sign? Suppose I had a sign made up with "150" in a red circle and put it up; does that make the speed limit 150km/h? If not, why not?

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question

Comment: It's in the original question: 'what law authorises whoever puts the signs there to do so?' I haven't yet found anything in the legislation cited so far that says anybody is actually authorised to put these speed signs up.